# How to shorten model names?

Tags: angularjs

I have a model that is complex, but for readability purposes, I'll make it simple here:

```
$scope.complexModel = {
    input1:{
        name: "foo",
        value: 1,
    },
    input2:{
        name: "bar",
        value: 1,
    },
};
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
<div ng-model="c as $scope.complexModel">
    <input ng-model="c.input1.name/>
    <input ng-model="c.input2.name/>
</div>
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what problem you are really trying to solve

Comment: When not just assign another variable to the scope? `$scope.c = $scope.complexModel`